# Having issue with the age verification js coding

Tags: javascript, verification

This is the first time to post a question here. I am working on the age verification page with drop down menu of birth date and submit button. It works great except one issue below.

After the user selects an age below the required age and fails the age gate, this user can still come back to the age check page to try selecting an older date of birth and this allows the user to successfully pass the age-gate. I would like to block those users who already entered an unqualified birth date from being able to go back and do this. I assume it is some type of cookie setting. However, I'm struggling to solve this issue and still beginner with javascript so any help or advise would be greatly appreciated.
The ageChecker.js code from [https://github.com/tmock12](https://github.com/tmock12/ageChecker)

```
var ageCheck = {

//Set the minimum age and where to redirect to
minimumAge : 17,
userIsOldEnoughPage : "index.html",
userNotOldEnoughPage : "age_unauthorized.html",


start: function() {
this.setUsersBirthday();
if (this.userIsOverMinimumAge()) {
  this.setCookie("usersBirthday",this.usersBirthday,30);
  window.location = this.userIsOldEnoughPage;
} else{
  this.notMinimumAge();
};
},

usersBirthday : new Date(),

setTheMonth : function() {
var selectedMonth = document.getElementById("month").value;
if (selectedMonth === "1") {
  this.setDaysForMonth(29);
}
else if (selectedMonth === "3" ||
         selectedMonth === "5" ||
         selectedMonth === "8" ||
         selectedMonth === "10") {
  this.setDaysForMonth(30);
}
else {
  this.setDaysForMonth(31);
};
},

setDaysForMonth : function(x) {
var daySelectTag = document.getElementsByName('day')[0];
daySelectTag.options.length = 0;
  for(var i=1; i <= x; i++) {
  daySelectTag.options.add(new Option(i, i));
}
},

setUsersBirthday: function() {
var usersMonth = document.getElementById("month").value;
var usersDay = document.getElementById("day").value;
var usersYear = document.getElementById("year").value;
this.usersBirthday.setMonth(usersMonth);
this.usersBirthday.setDate(usersDay);
this.usersBirthday.setFullYear(usersYear);
},

setMinimumAge: function() {
var today = new Date();
today.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() - this.minimumAge);
return today;
},

notMinimumAge : function() {
window.location = this.userNotOldEnoughPage
},

userIsOverMinimumAge: function () {
if (this.usersBirthday < this.setMinimumAge()) {
  return true;
}
},

setCookie: function (c_name,value,exMinutes) {
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setMinutes(exdate.getMinutes() + exMinutes);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exMinutes==null) ? "" : ";
                expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
},

getCookie: function (c_name) {
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
  {
    return unescape(x);
  }
}
},

checkCookie: function () {
var usersBirthday=this.getCookie("usersBirthday");
if (usersBirthday==null || usersBirthday=="") {
  window.location = "agegate.html";
}
}
}
```

Comment: This seems rather pointless … if you set a cookie, then they will most likely just delete that cookie and try again. If it even gets that far … I’d assume kids are smart enough to pick a fake, “older” birth date from the start.

Comment: This is my client's requirement and I'm pretty sure they know this age gate can be bypassed very easily however they want to set it something like this:
http://www.bandainamcogames.com/game/lords-of-the-fallen.html